# Erlang error with binary data

Tags: dns, binary, erlang

I just started my path on Erlang and I'm facing a problem I can't sort out a solution about:

I wrote a metod to take a domain espressed as a binary string, i.e. <<"www.404pagenotfound.com">> and convert it in the domain format as required for DNS protocol, so: <<3,"www",15,"pagenotfound",3,"com">>.

In the following the code (I rewroted it many times in different ways):

```
domainbyte(Bin) ->
    if byte_size(Bin) > 0 ->
        Res =  binary:split(Bin, <<".">>),
        [Chunk|[RestList]] = Res, 
        ChunkSize = byte_size(Chunk),   
        if length(RestList) > 0 -> 
            Rest = domainbyte(RestList),  %% <- Got "bad argument" here!
            <<ChunkSize/binary,Chunk,Rest>>;
        true ->
            <<ChunkSize/binary,Chunk>>
        end
    end.
```

Thx in advance for any clues.

PS.

Thx to comments I've found the error in the code abobe:

```
if length(RestList) > 0 -> %% here RestList is binary data so length throw "bad argument" error.
```

I've rewroted the method this way, but still with no luck:

**NOTE: I was able to fix the code in the following, problem is that if you have a binary chunk and you want to use it in another binary string, you must specify /binary on it: something not obvious to me.

I.e.: consider this small code snip:

**

TT = <<"com">>, 
SS = <<3, TT, 0>>  %% <- you get error: bad argument

**
must be fixed this way:
**

TT = <<"com">>, 
SS = <<3, TT/binary, 0>>

```
domainbyte(Bin) ->
    if byte_size(Bin) > 0 ->
        Res =  binary:split(Bin, <<".">>),
                if length(Res) > 1 -> 
                    [Chunk|[RestList]] = Res, 
                    ChunkSize = byte_size(Chunk),
                    Rest = domainbyte(RestList),
                    <<ChunkSize,Chunk,Rest>>;
                true -> 
                    [Chunk] = Res,
                    ChunkSize = byte_size(Chunk), 
                    <<ChunkSize,Chunk>>
                end
    end.
```

MdP

Comment: please don't hide your question in comments in the code...

Comment: Shouldn't the output from `<<"www.404pagenotfound.com">>` be `<<3,"www",15,"404pagenotfound",3,"com">>`?

Comment: Thx @rvirding, yes, it was a type, I corrected the original post.

Comment: @user1750572 Yes, you are right but the code as it stands will still crash, because of just what you have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to define the function using a binary comprehension:

```
domainbyte(Bin) ->
    Chunks = binary:split(Bin, <<".">>, [global]),      %A list of all the chunks
    << <<byte_size(C),C/binary>> || C <- Chunks >>.     %Build output binary
```

It might be slightly faster to build the output binary as a list of segments in a separate function then put them together in an `iolist_to_binary/1`. Note that if a '.' occurs outermost in the binary then this code will take that as an empty segment of length 0. If these should be discarded then you nee to add the option `trim` to `binary:split/3`. Note also that the size will occupy only **one** byte.

@Alnitak has the separate function but builds the binary one segment at time so it is not more efficient than the binary comprehension which does the same thing.

**N.B.** that if you have a binary segment `Chunk/binary` when constructing a binary this means that `Chunk` **IS** a binary, not that it should become one. Binaries are flat structures, think byte arrays, so everything becomes a binary. Or rather the binary.

**EDIT:** Though I see I missed the 0 which should be at the end. That is left as an exercise to the reader.

**EDIT:** Being in *teaching mode*, apart from the constructing binaries, a key to writing good **Erlang** code is understanding pattern matching. You use a bit but could do it more:

```
domainbyte(Bin) ->
    case binary:split(Bin, <<".">>) of
        [Chunk,Rest] ->                       %There was a '.'
            RestBin = domainbyte(Rest),
            Size = byte_size(Chunk),
            <<Size,Chunk/binary,RestBin/binary>>;
        [Chunk] ->                            %This was the last chunk
            Size = byte_size(Chunk),
            <<Size,Chunk/binary,0>>           %Add terminating 0
end.
```

This is basically doing the same as your code but we are using pattern matching to select a clause, not only to pull apart a known structure. Pattern matching is the basic method for control, not just in `case` as here but also in functions and `receive`. This results in `if` being used quite sparingly.

Enough from me for now.

Comment: Thx a lot, as told, I'm just an erlang newcomer and I completely missed comprenhension feature.... anyway, what about my second implementation ? Altought bad, seems correct to me, so, why I get error ? I'm trying to learn and such kind of errors are frustrating...   thx.

Comment: @user1750572 Comprehensions, list and binary, are a bit esoteric though in some cases they can lead to very concise and succinct code.

Comment: @user1750572 Just added a bit on an alternative way of writing your function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty on Erlang, but I think your problem is that `RestList` is an array of chunks from the output of `binary:split`.

So when you chuck it recursively back into `domainbyte` it's in the wrong format.

Also - don't forget the terminating NUL byte to represent the root label!

FWIW, here's my working version:

```
label([]) ->
    << 0 >>;

label([H|T]) ->
    D = label(H),
    P = label(T),
    << D/binary, P/binary>>;

label(A) ->
    L = byte_size(A),
    << <<L>>/binary, A/binary>>.

domainbyte(A) ->
    Res = binary:split(A, <<".">>, [global, trim]),
    label(Res).
```

It correctly adds a trailing NUL byte, and trims any extra trailing dots.

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply, but as you can see into the code, I already considered that:

Comment: As you can see I considered it: [Chunk|RestList]] = Res and thx for the NUL byte advice...

Comment: Are you sure about that additional set of `[]` around `RestList`?  Without the `global` option the `RestList` should just be the remaining parent domain label.  I'm trying to replicate this but my installed Erlang doesn't have the `binary` module.

Comment: hi @Alnitak, yes it is ok, in this source the problem is related to the length method used on binary data at row 6: if length(RestList) > 0. I've modified the code as in the following with another nasty prob. :(
 

`domainbyte(Bin) ->
 if byte_size(Bin) > 0 ->
 Res =  binary:split(Bin, <<".">>),
 if length(Res) > 1 -> 
  [Chunk|[RestList]] = Res, 
  ChunkSize = byte_size(Chunk),
  Rest = domainbyte(RestList),
  <<ChunkSize/binary,Chunk,Rest>>;
  true -> 
  [Chunk] = Res,
  ChunkSize = byte_size(Chunk),
  <<ChunkSize/binary,Chunk>>
  end
 end.`

Comment: You shouldn't really have the `label/1` function work on both the list of chunks as well as on each chunk. Though it would allow you to have nested lists of binaries and lists.

Comment: @rvirding well, I did say I was a bit rusty :)

Comment: Ahahahahahah... I'm rusty even before starting ... :P thx a lot to you all... lots of useful advices here .

Answer (score 0):

The concat of binaries should be written like this:

```
<< <<ChunkSize>>/binary, Chunk/binary, Rest/binary>>
% and
<< <<ChunkSize>>/binary, Chunk/binary>>
```

Comment: Thx @halfelf, just figured out ... :D